# How can I do a non-cumulative tensorflow scatter_add?

Tags: tensorflow

As part of learning my way around tensorflow I am converting some existing matrix-processing logic.  One of the steps is a scatter operation such as the one using scatter_add in the example below.  My problem with this example is that each time the operation is evaluated, it adds cumulatively on top of the previous result.  With the 3 run() calls as shown below, the results printed are:

```
[[8 12 8]...]
[[16 24 16]...]
[[24 36 24]...]
```

Whereas what I want is `[[8 12 8]...]` every time.  The `indices` vector contains duplicates, and the corresponding elements in `updates` need to be added together, but not to the existing value already held in `scattered`.

None of the scatter operations in the tensorflow documentation seem to be what I'm looking for.  Is there an appropriate operation to use?  If not, what is the best way to achieve what I need?

```
import tensorflow as tf

indices = tf.constant([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], tf.int32)

updates = tf.constant([
            [1., 2., 3., 4.],
            [2., 3., 4., 1.],
            [3., 4., 1., 2.],
            [4., 1., 2., 3.],
            [1., 2., 3., 4.],
            [2., 3., 4., 1.],
            [3., 4., 1., 2.],
            [4., 1., 2., 3.]], tf.float32)

scattered = tf.Variable([
            [0., 0., 0., 0.,],
            [0., 0., 0., 0.,]], tf.float32)

# Requirement:
# scattered[i, j] = Sum of updates[k, j] where indices[k] == i
#
# i.e.
#   scattered_data = [
#     [1+3+1+3, 2+4+2+4, 3+1+3+1, 4+2+4+2], 
#     [2+4+2+4, 3+1+3+1, 4+2+4+2, 1+3+1+3]]
#   == [
#     [ 8, 12,  8, 12],
#     [12,  8, 12,  8]]

scattered = tf.scatter_add(scattered, indices, updates, use_locking=True, name='scattered')
scattered_print = tf.Print(scattered, [scattered])

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(scattered_print)
# Printout: [[8 12 8]...]
sess.run(scattered_print)
# Printout: [[16 24 16]...]
sess.run(scattered_print)
# Printout: [[24 36 24]...]
sess.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following modification to the `scatter_add` call appears to make things work as desired:

```
with tf.control_dependencies([scattered.initializer]):
    scattered = tf.scatter_add(scattered, indices, updates, use_locking=True, name='scattered')
```

The rationale is that since I initialize the variable with zeros, forcing the initializer to rerun before every `scatter_add` operation will clear it out and avoid the cumulative updates.

This still seems somewhat clunky to me - I would have expected there to be a single-call solution.  And I'm not sure how much unnecessary memory allocation and freeing may be going on, but that's something to look into later, I think.