# Is `tf.Variable.scatter_nd_add` deterministic for repeated indices?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a list of indices in a `tf.Variable` where I want to add 1, but many of the indices will be repeated.

I know that `tf.scatter_nd` and relatives are non-deterministic when indices are repeated, but is `tf.Variable.scatter_nd_add` guaranteed to include all updates when indices are repeated? Or is it possible for a race condition to arise between simultaneous updates to the same index?

=== Update ===

Here is some example code. I know that something like the following is non-deterministic:

```
tf.scatter_add([[0], [0]], [0, 1], [1])
```

and can result in either `[0]` or `[1]`. What I want to know is whether the op for `scatter_nd_add` is guaranteed to perform all addition operations when the same index is accessed multiple times,

```
v = tf.Variable([0])
v.scatter_nd_add([[0], [0]], [1, 1])
tf.assert_equal(v, [2])
```

corresponding to

```
v1 <~ v[0]  # 0
v1 += 1     # 1
v[0] <~ v1
v2 <~ v[0]
v2 += 1     # 2
v[0] <~ v2
v[0] == 2
```

or whether this can fail due to staggered accesses and updates in e.g. a gpu:

```
v1 <~ v[0]  # 0
v2 <~ v[0]
v1 += 1     # 1
v[0] <~ v1
v2 += 1     # 1
v[0] <~ v2
v[0] == 1
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please sample code or some pseudo code ? you can also see following links for reference.                                                     
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711708/how-can-i-do-a-non-cumulative-tensorflow-scatter-add                                                      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68407576/how-to-modify-a-single-value-of-a-2d-tensor-programatically-by-index

Comment: @TensorflowSupport Hi, this is an old question, but I'd still appreciate an answer. I added code clarifying the question.